# Why is the area of an equilateral triangle $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}b^2$?

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

Why is the area of an equilateral triangle $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}b^2$$ and not $$\frac12b^2$$
or $$bh$$
[image]

Comment: Try drawing a diagram.

Comment: The area of a triangle is $\frac 12 b \cdot h$ where $b$ stands for "base" and $h$ stands for "height". If we orient an equilateral triangle so that its bottom side is horizontal, then $b$ is the base.  However, $b$ will not be the height of the triangle.

Comment: Why would the area be $\frac{1}{2}b^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equilateral triangle has three sides of equal length and three internal angles which are each $60^\circ$.

Imagine cutting the equilateral triangle in half by an altitude. This way, there are two right triangles which have the angle pattern $30^\circ−60^\circ−90^\circ$. This means the sides are in a ratio of $1:\sqrt{3}:2$.

If the altitude is drawn in, the base of the triangle is bisected, leaving two congruent segments with length $1/2$. The side opposite the $60^\circ$ angle, the height of the triangle, is just $\sqrt{3}$ times the existing side of $1/2$, so its length is ${\sqrt{3}}/2$.

Then, since the area of a triangle is $A=\frac{1}{2}bh$, we may deduce

[image]

Comment: would $\frac12b^2$ be the formula for a right isosceles triangle?

Comment: @Burt: Yes, since the base and height would both have the same length of $b$. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsoscelesRightTriangle.html).

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of side lengths in a $30-60-90$ triangle is $\frac12b:\frac{\sqrt3}2b:b$, where $b$ is the hypotenuse.  Its area, therefore, is $$\frac12\cdot\frac12b\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}2b=\frac{\sqrt3}8b^2.$$

Reflect the triangle across its $\frac{\sqrt3}2b$ side, and we get an equilateral triangle.  Its area would be double the area above, or $$2\left(\frac{\sqrt3}8b^2\right)=\frac{\sqrt3}4b^2$$
as desired.

Comment: The reasoning stands, albeit _reversed_; going backwards is typically how we derive the ratio of side lengths in the $30-60-90$ triangle.